# Text input in shiny table not updating after the first time

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I want my shiny app in R to read an Excel file, add empty row where user can add text input and after clicking a button, it updates the table with the added input and again one row at the top of the table will be empty, waiting for the user input. I've managed to make it work the first time, e.g. I can add input, click the button, the table is updated and the first line is waiting for another input. However, when I add again new input, the table is updated with the same text that I entered the first time.
It seems that the problem is somewhere in the line where I update the reactiveValues inside the observeEvent(), because when I delete that line, the print statement prints the correct input. When I keep that line, only the first input is always printed.

Many thanks for your help!

```
library(shiny)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(xlsx)
library(lubridate)

ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(column(4, offset = 0, actionButton("add_button", "Add", width = 200))), 
                br(),
                DT::dataTableOutput("outtable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    excel_file <- data.frame(Month = c("2024-01", "2023-12"), 
                             Date = c("2024-01-10", "2023-12-15"), 
                             Reviewer = c("A", "B"), 
                             Status = c("OK", "OK"), 
                             Comment = c("bla", "blabla"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    
    excel_file <- excel_file %>%
        arrange(desc(Month))
    
    df_input <- data.frame(
        Month = as.character(format(ym(max(excel_file$Month)) %m+% months(1), "%Y-%m")),
        Date = as.character(textInput("date", label = NULL)),
        Reviewer = as.character(textInput("reviewer", label = NULL)),
        Status = as.character(textInput("status", label = NULL)),
        Comment = as.character(textInput("comment", label = NULL)))
    
    
    RV <- reactiveValues(dat = bind_rows(df_input, excel_file))
    
    observeEvent(
        eventExpr   = c(input$add_button),
        handlerExpr = {
            new_line <- data.frame(
                Month = as.character(format(ym(max(RV$dat$Month)), "%Y-%m")),
                Date = input$date,
                Reviewer = input$reviewer,
                Status = input$status,
                Comment = input$comment)
            print(new_line)
            
            temp <- bind_rows(RV$dat, new_line) %>%
                arrange(desc(Month))
            
            RV$dat <- temp # THIS LINE 
        },ignoreNULL = FALSE , ignoreInit = TRUE
    )
    
    output$outtable <- DT::renderDataTable({
        datatable(
            RV$dat,
            selection="none",
            escape = FALSE, 
            options = list(
                dom = 'rtpi',
                autoWidth=TRUE,
                preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
            )
        )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a reactive dataframe in `datatable` to update the table. When it changes, the table is redrawn and the Shiny unbinding/binding is lost. Instead, one can use `replaceData` with a proxy.

```r
library(shiny)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(lubridate)

excel_file <- data.frame(
  Month = c("2024-01", "2023-12"), 
  Date = c("2024-01-10", "2023-12-15"), 
  Reviewer = c("A", "B"), 
  Status = c("OK", "OK"), 
  Comment = c("bla", "blabla"), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

excel_file <- excel_file %>% arrange(desc(Month))

df_input <- data.frame(
  Month = as.character(format(ym(max(excel_file$Month)) %m+% months(1), "%Y-%m")),
  Date = as.character(textInput("date", label = NULL)),
  Reviewer = as.character(textInput("reviewer", label = NULL)),
  Status = as.character(textInput("status", label = NULL)),
  Comment = as.character(textInput("comment", label = NULL))
)

dat <- bind_rows(df_input, excel_file)


ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      4, 
      offset = 0, 
      actionButton("add_button", "Add", width = 200)
    )
  ), 
  br(),
  DTOutput("outtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  Dat <- reactiveVal(dat)

  output$outtable <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      dat,
      selection = "none",
      escape = FALSE, 
      options = list(
        dom = 'rtpi',
        autoWidth = TRUE,
        preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
        drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
      )
    )
  })
  
  proxy <- dataTableProxy("outtable")
  
  observeEvent(
    eventExpr   = input$add_button,
    handlerExpr = {

      dat0 <- Dat()
      
      new_line <- data.frame(
        Month = as.character(format(ym(max(dat0$Month)), "%Y-%m")),
        Date = input$date,
        Reviewer = input$reviewer,
        Status = input$status,
        Comment = input$comment
      )

      dat1 <- bind_rows(dat0, new_line) %>% arrange(desc(Month))
      
      Dat(dat1)
      
      replaceData(proxy, dat1, resetPaging = FALSE)
      
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```